# $.getJSON não funcionando como deveria para obter imagem graph API

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

tenho esse seguinte código onde retorno comentários de uma postagem no facebook.

```
function pegaFoto(id){
    var url2 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/' + from[id] + '/picture?fields=url';
    $.getJSON(url2, function(res2){
    for (var key2 in res2.data) {
        foto[id] = res2.data[key2].url;
        console.log(res2.data[key2].url);
    }
});

}

function refreshCounts() {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/********_*********/comments?fields=from{id}, message&access_token=' + access_token;
    $.getJSON(url, function(res){
        for (var key in res.data) {
            comentario[key] = res.data[key].message;
            from[key] = res.data[key].from.id;
            pegaFoto(key);
            console.log(comentario[key]);     
            console.log(foto[key]);
        }
    });

}
```

O que é estranho, é que a segunda função funciona perfeitamente e a de cima não funciona. a variável url2 está sendo setada corretamente mas o $.getJSON não executa e não tenho a mínima idéia do porque

Comment: Se você pegar a `url` e jogar no navegador, retorna os dados?

Comment: retorna sim amigo

Comment: `from[id]` não seria somente `id`? De onde é o `from`?

Comment: não, está correto assim. id na verdade é o index do array que contém os ids de pessoas que comentaram. Única coisa que não está dando certo é o get.JSON que não é executado, pois a url2 esta setada normalmente quando verifico

Comment: cara, eu fiz um teste usando o facebook do mark: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/4/picture?fields=url. O retorno não é um JSON, é uma imagem. Você vai ter que usar `$.ajax` e tratar essa imagem. Ou passar algum argumento na url que converte o retorno para JSON.

Comment: não tinha percebido isso. Pois no graph api explorer retorna json, que tenso perdi horas por causa dessa "confusão"

Comment: Pois é, estou lendo a documentação pra ver se descubro algo..

Comment: Qual a dica então? Não sou muito experiente com ajax, programo por hobby e ja to acostumado com a API do face mas por essa eu não esperava, preciso retornar a url da imagem

Comment: Consegui mano, graças a essa sacada de aparecer a foto e não os dados, eu simplesmente precisei incluir no fim da url o parametro `redirect=false` e deu certinho obrigado

Comment: Que bom :) outra forma é invocar a api deles no javascript. Mas se já deu certo melhor ainda.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca Responda sua pergunta com essa solução, para quando alguém procurar talvez sua solução seja útil.

Comment: @LucasCosta aceitei sua resposta, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que ao chamar direto a URL da graph api o retorno é uma imagem, não um JSON. Você vai ter que usar a *api* do facebook para fazer a chamada e ter o retorno em formato JSON. Algo como:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'your-app-id',
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function pegar() {
    FB.api(
        '/4/picture',
        'GET', {},
        function(response) {
            console.log(response); // irá exibir o mesmo retorno da graph explorer
        }
    );
```

O retorno será parecido com esse (retirado da graph explorer):

```
{
  "data": {
    "is_silhouette": false,
    "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xat1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12208495_10102454385528521_4749095086285673716_n.jpg?oh=1a5f0703065fe96c49224e520644fff9&oe=58C3A170&__gda__=1489734487_29708b5f264ecdf1dac103a35df9e726"
  }
}
```

Para inicializar a api veja essa documentação: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.init/v2.8

Se tiver mais dúvida tem o quickstart [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/).

### Editado

É possível obter o retorno como JSON por ajax incluindo no final da URL `redirect=false`. A URL ficaria:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/4/picture?redirect=false
```